# Syntax error while passing arguments to JavaScript function from Django template

Tags: javascript, django

I have to pass 4 arguments from a Django template to a JavaScript function. Out of these 4, 3 are integers/decimals and 1 is a string.

```
<button onclick="addCart({{ item.id }}, {{ item.price }}, {{ item.discount }}, {{item.name}})">
               Add to cart
</button>
```

Here is the Javascript function.

```
let USER_CART = [];
function addCart(itemId, itemPrice, itemDiscount, itemName) {
    let itemQuantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(itemId).value);
    if (itemQuantity > 0) {
        let item_index = USER_CART.findIndex(item => item.id === itemId);
        if (item_index === -1) {
            let item = {
                id: itemId,
                price: itemPrice,
                discount: itemDiscount,
                quantity: itemQuantity,
                title: itemName,
            };
            USER_CART.push(item);
        } else {
            USER_CART[item_index].quantity += itemQuantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click on the button this error shows up on the console.

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Another interesting thing is if I remove the `item.name` and `itemName` completely from the code, it works just fine.

Comment: You need to wrap the string argument in (single) quotes: `'{{ item.name }}'` With errors like this, always check the source code in the browser first (Ctrl+U).

Comment: @ChrisG Yes. I should have checked the generated HTML first, I was too focused on the JavaScript part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes around `{{item.name}}`.

```
<button onclick="addCart({{ item.id }}, {{ item.price }}, {{ item.discount }}, '{{item.name}}')">
               Add to cart
</button>
```